# MYSQL SUM() returns incorrect value. No joins

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sum

Having an issue with a simple SUM() of a column

```
SELECT SUM('2021-06-30_value') FROM Test.a123;
```

Returns 198058

Pulling the same data into Excel as well as doing a python for loop for each row returns 2537737 << the correct value.

Comment: SUM what? You haven't selected a column. I don't actually know what that query is going to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
SELECT SUM('2021-06-30_value') FROM Test.a123;
```

Is doing the sum of a string, not a column.  The string itself is converted to a number, based on the leading digits, so it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM(2021) FROM Test.a123;
```

You presumably want a column, so you need backticks:

```
SELECT SUM(`2021-06-30_value`) FROM Test.a123;
```

*Never* use single quotes for column names, because they are confused with strings.  Also, you should name columns so they don't need to be escaped.  I might suggest `value_20210630`, for instance.

Comment: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations?view=sql-server-ver15) as I suspected as much. I guess this behaviour will hold across pretty much all RDBMS?

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that fixed the issue. 
Also really appreciate the pointers with the table names

Comment: @roganjosh . . . Most databases will return an error on a non-numeric string used in an arithmetic context.  So, this will fail in most databases.